# Having some trouble clearing a textbox - tkinter - Python

Tags: python, text, tkinter

I've read a few threads all over the internet regarding clearing a text box on tkinter. Basically everyone says it's simple:

```
text.delete("1.0", END)
```

However, perhaps it has something to do with the way I structured it, or the way I'm calling it, but for some reason, this does not work for me. It simply does nothing.

I've tried re-positioning the `def`, and re-writing the `text.delete("1.0", END)` in a number of ways, most of which lead me to other errors, but I cannot seem to get this to work.

Ultimately, what I'm trying to accomplish is that when I click a button, the text box will clear, before populating with new information.

Below is my code.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import functions

class MainWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("pyTicket")

# TOOLBAR ####################################################
        toolbar = Frame(self.parent, bd=1, relief=RAISED)

        self.img = Image.open("Icons\startupcheck.png")
        eimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
        startupButton = Button(toolbar, text="Re-Check ", image=eimg, compound="left", relief=RAISED, command=self.StartUpChecker)
        startupButton.image = eimg
        startupButton.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=2, pady=2)

        toolbar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

        self.parent.config(menu=menubar)
        self.pack(anchor=N, side=TOP, fill=X, expand=False)
# TOOLBAR ####################################################

# TEXTBOX ####################################################
        self.textbox = Text(self, wrap="word", height=5)
        self.textbox.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.textbox.tag_configure("TextBox", foreground="#b22222")
        self.pack(anchor=S, side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
# TEXTBOX ####################################################

# Functions ###################################################
    def StartUpChecker(self):
        self.clear_text()
        functions.StartUpChecker()

    def clear_text(self):
        self.textbox.delete("1.0", END)

class TextRedirector(object):
    def __init__(self, widget, tag="stdout"):
        self.widget = widget
        self.tag = tag

    def write(self, str):
        self.widget.configure(state="normal")
        self.widget.insert("end", str, (self.tag,))
        self.widget.configure(state="disabled")    
def main():
    root = Tk()
    #Width X Height
    root.geometry("500x300+300+300")
    root.update()
    root.minsize(400,200)
    app = MainWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: That should work. Just to see if it the problem is at somewhere else, can you please comment out functions.StartUpChecker() line, then try again?

Comment: When I comment it out, it then does nothing. The button seem unresponsive.

Comment: This was already resolved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't appear to actually use the `TextRedirector` class in the code you posted, but if you're using it in your actual code, note that its `.write()` method leaves the textbox in a disabled state - which prevents ALL modifications, even those resulting from code instead of direct user action.  Your `.clear_text()` method needs to temporarily enable the textbox so that you can modify it, exactly as `.write()` does.

Comment: OMG, I see what you're saying, I changed the state to `normal` and the clear text is working as expected. The TextRedirector is a small function I found online to print console output into a tkinter textbox. I didn't even notice that `state="disabled"` Thank you!